# How does the VisibilityEnabler work?

Tags: godot, documentation, visibility-determination

I'm confused about the use of the Visibility enabler node in Godot. I've read the documentation and tried it out both stand-alone and as a child without success.

I set the parent to print a `String` during its `_process` function. Despite adding the enabler, it continued to print despite being off screen.

How do I set it up so that It actually disables anything?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you disabled was the canvas visibility. That just disables the render's process for the nodes and its childs. If you really want to stop the `_process(delta)` method. You must find the Stop property, which by default is **inherited**, and set it to **stop**.

You can also stop the call of process by setting `set_process` to false through the script.

Comment: I'm sorry, disabling canvas visibility disables process for just any node or children of the enabler?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation on `VisibilityEnabler`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_visibilityenabler.html) again:

> The VisibilityEnabler will disable RigidBody and AnimationPlayer nodes when they are not visible. It will only affect other nodes within the same scene as the VisibilityEnabler itself.

It has nothing to do with `_process`.

---

If you want to disable `_process`, you can use `set_process(false)` on whatever `Node` you want to disable it (you can also disable other methods), which you might do from a script attached to a `VisibilityNotifier` handling its own signals.

*Sadly we cannot fully disable a script in Godot 3.x. In Godot 4.x you would use `process_mode` for that. The equivalent of `process_mode` in Godot 3.x is `pause_mode` but there isn't an option to always stop (The "Stop" option makes the `Node` stop when the scene tree is [`paused`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.5/classes/class_scenetree.html#class-scenetree-property-paused)).*

---

For reference in Godot 4 the role of `VisibilityEnabler` is taken by `VisibleOnScreenEnabler3D`, and the role of `VisibilityNotifier` is taken by `VisibleOnScreenNotifier3D`, and of course there are 2D counterparts as well.

*Yes, I see this is an old question.*